# Android FrameLayout Child Negative Margin Odd Effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view, android-viewgroup

I made a custom `View` that is used to show feedback in the UI (usually in response to an action being taken). When `FeedbackView.showText` is called, it will animate the `View` in for 2 seconds, and then animate it out. This is done using `translationY`.

If I apply a negative margin to it that is greater than its height the first time `FeedbackView.showText` is called it doesn't animate in correctly; it just appears (or in some cases doesn't display at all). Subsequent calls to `FeedbackView.showText` cause the correct animation.

In `activity_main.xml` below, the `FeedbackView` has a margin top of `-36dp`, which is greater than its height (when non-negated). If the margin top is changed to `-35dp` it animates correctly even the first time `FeedbackView.showText` is called.

Does anyone know why something like this would happen?

Romain Guy has said that [it is OK to use negative margins on `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293558/error-in-xml-layout-cant-convert-to-dimension-15/5293636#5293636). My only guess is that they are not OK with `FrameLayout`s.

**FeedbackView.java**

```
public class FeedbackView extends FrameLayout {
  public static final int DEFAULT_SHOW_DURATION = 2000;

  private AtomicBoolean showing = new AtomicBoolean(false);
  private AtomicBoolean animating = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  private float heightOffset;

  private Runnable animateOutRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      animateContainerOut();
    }
  };

  public FeedbackView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  public FeedbackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
  }

  public FeedbackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  public FeedbackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
    setAlpha(0);
  }

  public boolean isShowing() {
    return showing.get();
  }

  public void showText(Context context, String text) {
    removeCallbacks(animateOutRunnable);

    heightOffset = getMeasuredHeight();

    removeAllViews();

    final TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
    tv.setText(text);

    addView(tv);

    if(!showing.getAndSet(true)) {
      animateContainerIn();
    }
    else {
      tv.setTranslationY(-getHeight());
      tv.animate().translationY(0).start();
    }

    postDelayed(animateOutRunnable, DEFAULT_SHOW_DURATION);
  }

  private void animateContainerIn() {
    if(animating.getAndSet(true)) {
      animate().cancel();
    }

    ViewPropertyAnimator animator = animate();
    long startDelay = animator.getDuration() / 2;

    animate()
        .alpha(1)
        .setStartDelay(startDelay)
        .start();

    animate()
        .translationY(heightOffset)
        .setStartDelay(0)
        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            animating.set(false);
            showing.set(true);
          }
        })
        .start();
  }

  private void animateContainerOut() {
    showing.set(false);

    if(animating.getAndSet(true)) {
      animate().cancel();
    }

    ViewPropertyAnimator animator = animate();
    long duration = animator.getDuration();

    animate()
        .alpha(0)
        .setDuration(duration / 2)
        .start();

    animate()
        .translationY(-heightOffset)
        .setDuration(duration)
        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            animating.set(false);
          }
        })
        .start();
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private FeedbackView feedbackView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    feedbackView = (FeedbackView) findViewById(R.id.feedback);

    findViewById(R.id.show_feedback).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        feedbackView.showText(MainActivity.this, "Feedback");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:clickable="true"/>

  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="90dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:background="#e9e9e9"/>

    <negative.margin.FeedbackView
      android:id="@+id/feedback"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="35dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="-36dp"
      android:background="#20ACE0"/>

  </FrameLayout>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/show_feedback"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:text="Show Feedback"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the negative `margin` is not the **direct** cause of your animation failing.

You would probably achieve the same (undesired) effect - animation not being performed - if you set for example: `layout_marginLeft` to the value equal to the `Activity` `width` (so a positive value).

The problem is that your `View` is completely "outside" of the visible area therefore when your `Activity` is being created, the `View` is not being rendered right away. And running an animation on a `View` that has not been rendered yet, will not be performed.

More information (for example) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9661832/1993204).

What you can do to fix it is:

- Rebuild your layout in the way that your `View` is within the rendered area (so basically is within the visible area), but its `visibility` is set to `View.INVISIBLE`. At the start of the animation (use an `AnimationListener` or `AnimatorListener` or something ;) ) set its `visibility` to `View.VISIBLE`.
- Rebuild your animation so it does not use `ViewPropertyAnimator` (the `animate()` method call), but an `Animation` `Object`. And start it on a different `View` (on one that you are sure has already been rendered) - for example on the `View's` `ViewParent` (which you can get with `getParent()`).
- You can **try** (my guts tell me that should work, but you would need to test it) to set your layouts `clipChildren` and `clipToPadding` to `false`, forcing your views to be rendered even when outside of the visibile area. If you try that solution (and I think you should, because you won't have to change that much - just add `android:clipChildren="false"`,`android:clipToPadding="false"` to all of your `layouts` in this `Activity`) please tell me if it worked.